# iOS Swift: presented view controller is nil

Tags: ios, wifi, modalviewcontroller

I'm trying to know which is the presented view controller of a modal view controller shown by a modal segue..

`print(self.presentedViewController)` is always `nil`, how is it possible?

Comment: Where is that line of code?

Comment: in viewdidload.

Comment: while the view is being loaded, it cannot be presenting any view controller.. I would wonder how it is possible, if it was not nil

Comment: I just want to know who is the parent, where should I put that line of code?

Comment: in `viewDidLoad` of the modal view you are showing? If so, *that* view controller is ***not*** presenting a VC, so of course it will be nil. Do you want to get the VC that *presented* this VC?

Comment: @DonMag yes.. exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the "parent" view controller of the view controller you are in, you want to get the "presenting" controller:

```
print(self.presentingViewController)
```

If your code is in the VC that just *presented* a modal VC, in *that* code you can call:

```
print(self.presentedViewController)
```

to get a reference to the *modal* VC.

Answer (score 0):

Weird, it kept returning `nil` in `viewDidLoad`, however, when I wrapped my `print` in timeout, it returned it correctly:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.0) {
    print("test", self.presentingViewController)
}
```

Comment: It returns nil because when viewDidLoad is called, there is no guarantee that the view controller hierarchy is loaded in the navigation tree. In order for to work you should call it in view will appear